# IPsec tunnels between Linux and Solaris

Tags: linux, debian, solaris, ipsec, opensolaris

I have a Solaris machine sitting out in the ether somewhere that I would like to make part of my network via IPsec. I have this working between Solaris machines but not between Solaris and Linux.

I think the basic problem is that Solaris only does IPsec tunnel mode in the same ways as Cisco IPsec Virtual Tunnel Interfaces - i.e. an IP-in-IP tunnel secured by IPsec. I don't really know how to replicate this on Linux. I do want the tunnel to have an IP address, because the remote host isn't routing a local network - just itself.

### Solaris

The Solaris config looks like this:

```
# ipsecinit.conf
{tunnel ip.tun0 negotiate tunnel}
  ipsec {encr_algs AES-CBC encr_auth_algs HMAC-SHA1 auth_algs HMAC-SHA1 sa shared}
# hsotname.ip.tun0
130.95.13.254 130.95.13.253 tsrc 192.168.13.20 tdst 130.95.13.20 router up
# ike.config
{ label "manduba192-musundo"
  local_addr 192.168.13.20
  remote_addr 130.95.13.20
  p1_xform
   { auth_method preshared oakley_group 5 auth_alg sha1 encr_alg aes }
  p2_pfs 5
}
```

This produces SAs that look like this:

```
SA: flags=0xc0038000 < X_USED X_PAIRED X_OUTBOUND X_UNIQUE X_TUNNEL >
SRC: Source address (proto=4/ipip)
SRC: AF_INET: port 0, 192.168.13.20 (manduba192.ucc.gu.uwa.edu.au).
DST: Destination address (proto=4/ipip)
DST: AF_INET: port 0, 130.95.13.20 (musundo.ucc.gu.uwa.edu.au).
INS: Inner source address (proto=0/<unspecified>)
INS: AF_INET: port 0, 0.0.0.0 <unspecified>.
IND: Inner destination address (proto=0/<unspecified>)
IND: AF_INET: port 0, 0.0.0.0 <unspecified>.
KMC: Protocol 1, cookie="manduba192-musundo" (3)
```

---

### Linux

I don't really know how to replicate this in Linux. I've tried this:

```
spdadd 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 any -P out ipsec
    esp/tunnel/130.95.13.126-192.168.13.20/use
    ah/tunnel/130.95.13.126-192.168.13.20/use;

spdadd 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 any -P in ipsec
    esp/tunnel/192.168.13.20-130.95.13.126/use
    ah/tunnel/192.168.13.20-130.95.13.126/use;
```

which I can then presumably put an IPIP tunnel over the top of? But the IKE negotiation fails due to SPD mismatch.

Any ideas?

Comment: I never did get this working - though an ipip tunnel protected by IPsec might have worked. Ended up just putting a Solaris box inside the target network to create the tunnel.